# Here he works out of WHILE. Inside it does not work, Why?

Tags: php, pdo

Inside the WHILE the avatar (); not work. And it works outside the WHILE. How do I operate the function within the WHILE?

```
try{
     $this->conex->beginTransaction();
     $query = $this->conex->prepare("SELECT idUser FROM usuario WHERE id = :id ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT $pagin, $paginaF");
     $query->bindParam(":id", $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20); 
     $query->execute();
     while ($lista = $query->fetch()){
       $idUser = $lista['idUser'];
       echo "<div id='avatar'>"box::avatar($idUser)."</div>";
     }    
//Here he works out of WHILE. Inside it does not work...
echo box::avatar($idUser);
$this->conex->commit();
}catch (PDOException $ex) {
     echo "Erro: " . $ex->getMessage();
}

public function avatar($idUser){
     $idUser = (int) $idUser;
     $query = $this->conex->prepare("SELECT avatar FROM login WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
     $query->bindParam(":id", $idUser, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
     $query->execute();
     while ($avatar = $query->fetch()){
         $avatar = $avatar['avatar'];
     }
  return $avatar;
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, can you clarify what you mean? I can think of (a) It goes inside the loop but doesn't execute the avatar method. and (b) It doesn't even go inside the loop.

Comment: What is the value of $idUser outside the loop? It should be undefined, according to this code.

Comment: @The Guy Of Doom @Adarsh R PDO doesn't support nested queries.

You need to read the entire set of IDs into an array first, and then loop over that array again to produce your output.

Comment: Why did you repeat @Alnitak's answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDO [doesn't support](http://www.fischerlaender.net/php/pdo-mysql-and-nested-queries) nested queries.

You need to read the entire set of IDs into an array first, and *then* loop over that array again to produce your output, e.g.:

```
 $ids = array();
 $query->execute();
 while ($lista = $query->fetch()){
   $ids[] = $lista['idUser'];
 }

 foreach ($ids as $idUser) {
   echo "<div id='avatar'>" . box::avatar($idUser) . "</div>";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you help me? as I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Syntax error, you are missing a concatination dot:

```
echo "<div id='avatar'>" . box::avatar($idUser)."</div>"
```

Comment: "<div id='avatar'>" . box::avatar($idUser)."</div>";
It did not work

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no records in your table matching the condition

Comment: Yes, I also thought about it. More has the record in the table. Outside WHILE it works.