# foreach data while inside?

Tags: php, pdo

Good afternoon, everybody. I have a doubt.

I have a WHILE, and accurate list of the data within it FOREACH . Does anyone know how to do this?

I would be very grateful for the help.

Example code.

```
     $UserIDS= array();
     $query->execute();
     while ($lista = $query->fetch()){
      $mensagem = $lista['mensagem'];
      $UserIDS[] = $lista['idUser'];
      echo
         '
           //Data from Forech, was shown here.
             <div class="avatar"></div>

             <div class="text">
             '.utf8_encode($mensagem).'
             </div>
          ';
     }
     //FOREACH data has to list before the $message, if put into the forech WHILE not sure of the fact that I have an array inside.

     foreach ($UserIDS as $idUsua) {
      echo "<div class='avatar'>".box::avatar($idUsua)."</div>";
     }
```

Anyone know how do I pull data from FOREACH and put inside the   in WHILE? be very grateful for the help.

Comment: What is the structure of the data returned from the query?

Comment: Its not completely clear what you are trying to do, can you give us some info about the data you are querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079441/here-he-works-out-of-while-inside-it-does-not-work-why/5079476#5079476) to your other question:

```
// fetch all the data in one go
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll();

// and then iterate it
foreach ($data as $lista) {
  echo "<div id='avatar'>" . box::avatar($lista['idUser']) . "</div>";
  echo "<div class='text'>" . utf8_encode($lista['mensagem']). "</div>";
}
```

Your existing `box::avatar` call is then still free (as before) to make separate PDO query calls.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you take this part

```
foreach ($UserIDS as $idUsua) {
  echo "<div class='avatar'>".box::avatar($idUsua)."</div>";
 }
```

into a function like

```
function userId($UserIDS){
     $userAvatarDivs="";
     foreach ($UserIDS as $idUsua) {
        $userAvatarDivs.= "<div class='avatar'>".box::avatar($idUsua)."</div>";
     }
     return $userAvatarDivs;
 }
```

and call it on

```
while ($lista = $query->fetch()){
  $mensagem = $lista['mensagem'];
  $UserIDS[] = $lista['idUser'];
  echo
     '
       //Data from Forech, was shown here.
         <div class="avatar"></div>

         <div class="text">
         '.utf8_encode($mensagem).'
         </div>
      '.userId($UserIDS);
 }
```

Comment: It did not work. I want this data from within the foreach WHILE. while ($lista = $query->fetch()){
  $mensagem = $lista['mensagem'];
  $UserIDS[] = $lista['idUser'];
  echo
     '
       //Data from Forech, was shown here.
         <div class="avatar">'.userId($UserIDS).'</div>

         <div class="text">
         '.utf8_encode($mensagem).'
         </div>
      '
 }